# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I work with a Spring boot project with MySQL database and the entities are provided,

The IP address entity,

```
@Entity
public class IpAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "IP_ADDR_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "IP_ADDRESS")
    @NotEmpty
    private String address;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ipAddresses")
    private List<HttpInfoMessage> httpInfoMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    public IpAddress() {
    }

    public IpAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public IpAddress(String address, List<HttpInfoMessage> httpInfoMessages) {
        this.address = address;
        this.httpInfoMessages = httpInfoMessages;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<HttpInfoMessage> getHttpInfoMessages() {
        return httpInfoMessages;
    }

    public void setHttpInfoMessages(List<HttpInfoMessage> httpInfoMessages) {
        this.httpInfoMessages = httpInfoMessages;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof IpAddress)) return false;

        IpAddress ipAddress = (IpAddress) o;

        if (!getId().equals(ipAddress.getId())) return false;
        return getAddress().equals(ipAddress.getAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getAddress().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IpAddress{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The Http message entity,

```
@Entity
public class HttpInfoMessage {

    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
    private Long statusId;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    @NotEmpty
    private String status;

    public HttpInfoMessage() {

    }

    public HttpInfoMessage(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public HttpInfoMessage(Long statusId, String status) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public HttpInfoMessage(Long statusId, String status, List<IpAddress> ipAddresses) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
        this.status = status;
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }

    public Long getStatusId() {
        return statusId;
    }

    public void setStatusId(Long statusId) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    //    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "httpInfoMessages")
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "IP_ADDR_STATUS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "STATUS_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IP_ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName = "IP_ADDR_ID"))
    private List<IpAddress> ipAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<IpAddress> getIpAddresses() {
        return ipAddresses;
    }

    public void setIpAddresses(List<IpAddress> ipAddresses) {
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof HttpInfoMessage)) return false;

        HttpInfoMessage httpInfoMessage1 = (HttpInfoMessage) o;

        if (!getStatusId().equals(httpInfoMessage1.getStatusId())) return false;
        return getStatus().equals(httpInfoMessage1.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getStatusId().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getStatus().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Status{" +
                "statusId=" + statusId +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I read the server log entries from a text file and perform some manipulation on them and eventually, I get the `List<IpAddress>`.

After I get the `List<IpAddress>`, I printed them just to show,

```
The IP list size is = 5

IP address = IpAddress{id=null, address='177.132.239.67'}
Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}
Status{statusId=404, status='404_Not Found'}
Status{statusId=405, status='405_Method Not Allowed'}
Status{statusId=406, status='406_Not Acceptable'}

IP address = IpAddress{id=null, address='178.133.239.67'}
Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}
Status{statusId=404, status='404_Not Found'}
Status{statusId=405, status='405_Method Not Allowed'}
Status{statusId=406, status='406_Not Acceptable'}

IP address = IpAddress{id=null, address='175.130.239.67'}
Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}
Status{statusId=404, status='404_Not Found'}
Status{statusId=405, status='405_Method Not Allowed'}
Status{statusId=406, status='406_Not Acceptable'}

IP address = IpAddress{id=null, address='176.131.239.67'}
Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}
Status{statusId=404, status='404_Not Found'}
Status{statusId=405, status='405_Method Not Allowed'}
Status{statusId=406, status='406_Not Acceptable'}

IP address = IpAddress{id=null, address='174.129.239.67'}
Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}
Status{statusId=404, status='404_Not Found'}
Status{statusId=405, status='405_Method Not Allowed'}
Status{statusId=406, status='406_Not Acceptable'}
```

I then tried to save all the entries by iterating through them,

```
ipAddresses.forEach(
                ipAddress -> {
                    ipAddressService.save(ipAddress);
                }
        );
```

I get the error at the time of saving the entries,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '403' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I can provide more info if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the IpAddress object has a list of HttpInfoMessage objects which uses the statusId field as ID in the database. An ID has to be unique.

But you use the CascadeType.ALL for those collections, which means HttpInfoMessage objects will be saved too.

So when you try to save the `Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden'}` a second time you get the exception, because of the id already exists. That is simple database stuff and you have to fix this. How, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I guess assigning an `IpAddress` `id` column in the `HttpInfoMessage` table will solve the issue though I wonder how to do it. In that time, It will save like `Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden', id=1}`, `Status{statusId=403, status='403_Forbidden', id=2}` etc and will be unique. I will open know any other better solution as well.

Comment: If I use the `CascadeType.MERGE` or `CascadeType.DETACH`, it will populate only the `ip_address` table. I would prefer to populate all the tables if possible. Please advice

Comment: What you suggest is a OneToMany relation. Look here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany, if you want to know how to do it. For me the values are static ones, so I would use an enum or database table with enumerated values

Answer (score 1):

In your httpService-Entity the `statusId` field is the primary key. Your testdata has the values 403-406 set in `statusId` in every `IpAddress`-Block. If you remove the values from `statusId` and set them to null it should work.

Comment: How do I remove the values from `statusId`?

Comment: Do you create the List<IpAddress> manually? Then you also set the value on Status.statusId manually. Otherwise you have to iterate over all Status-elements and call sth. like status.setStatusId=null.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put non-unique http-status codes as Id's statusId which is unique.

As you have your entities provided and you can't change them you have to make shure you are correctly inserting values as a status. For me with entity like that you can put a technical(generated) id to statusId and a name of your status('403_Forbidden' or simply '403') to status column.